# Exported bash functions sometimes visible from Perl

Tags: bash, environment-variables, function

My Redhat 9, OpenBSD 4.9, FreeBSD 10, Macos X, LinuxMint 17.3, and Ubuntu 14.04.4 all print OK when running this:

```
myfunc() { echo OK; }
export -f myfunc
perl -e open\(\$fh,\"\|-\",\"@ARGV\"\)\;close\$fh\; /bin/bash\ -c\ myfunc\\\ a
```

My Ubuntu 16.04.1 gives:

```
bash: myfunc: command not found
```

But if I remove `\\\ a` it works.

```
perl -e open\(\$fh,\"\|-\",\"@ARGV\"\)\;close\$fh\; /bin/bash\ -c\ myfunc
```

I have the feeling something is configured wrongly on my system, but what should I look for?

**Edit**

thrig found a shorter version that also fails. Using that I straced on a failing and a non-failing system:

```
stdout strace -ff perl -e 'system @ARGV' /bin/bash\ -c\ myfunc\\\ a|grep bash
```

Failing:

```
execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-e", "system @ARGV", "/bin/bash -c myfunc\\ a"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
[pid  7728] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/bin/bash -c myfunc\\ a"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
[pid  7729] execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "myfunc a"], [/* 70 vars */]) = 0
```

Non-failing:

```
execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-e", "system @ARGV", "/bin/bash -c myfunc\\ a"], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
[pid 26497] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/bin/bash -c myfunc\\ a"], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
[pid 26498] execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "myfunc a"], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
```

That looks awfully similar. Removing the `\\\ a` gives on both systems:

```
execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-e", "system @ARGV", "/bin/bash -c myfunc"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
[pid  7826] execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "myfunc"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
```

So Perl drops the `sh -c` if there is only a single command. Maybe `sh -c` eats the function on the Ubuntu 16.04?

`/bin/sh` is `dash` on both systems.

**Edit2**

`env` shows the function. This displays the function as part of the environment on both systems:

```
perl -e 'system @ARGV' /bin/bash\ -c\ env
```

Ubuntu 16.04 and one working system:

```
BASH_FUNC_myfunc%%=() {  echo OK
}
```

Other working system:

```
BASH_FUNC_myfunc()=() {  echo OK
}
```

But this shows only the definition on the working systems:

```
perl -e 'system @ARGV' /bin/bash\ -c\ env';true'
```

**Edit3**

Workaround:

```
myfunc() { echo OK; }
export -f myfunc
perl -e open\(\$fh,\"\|-\",@ARGV\)\;close\$fh\; /bin/bash -c myfunc\ a
```

Comment: Slightly less obfuscated (second version): `perl -e 'open($fh, "|-", @ARGV); close $fh;' "/bin/bash -c myfunc"`   These both return "OK" on OS X.

Comment: Same behaviour on OpenBSD 6.0-beta as on Ubuntu 16.04.1, BTW.

Comment: `perl -e 'system @ARGV'` would be even more concise, and also removes the confusing backwhacks.

Comment: @Kusalananda Can I ask you to test the workaround on OpenBSD?

Comment: The workaround in "Edit3" returns `OK` on OpenBSD (I had to change the path to `bash` as there's no `bash` in `/bin`).

Comment: [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29)?

Comment: @Cyrus Nope: As you can see one of the other working systems exports the function using the %% syntax, too.

Comment: i'm wondering why you're escaping everything rather than just quoting?  e.g. `perl -e "system ('bash','-c','declare -fp myfunc')"`.  or `perl -e 'system @ARGV' -- bash -c 'declare -pF myfunc'`

Comment: @cas Because the escaping is done by a program (GNU Parallel).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `/bin/sh` from systems like Debian or Ubuntu (`dash`) or OpenBSD will [clear from the environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498952/308316) any variables whose names contain fancy chars like `%`, and that includes those `BASH_FUNC_foo%%=() { ...`, which are used to encode bash's exported functions.

If the `|-` from the `open` function is followed by a single argument instead of a list of arguments, and that argument contains any shell metacharacters (the backslash is one of those), then perl will pass it as an argument to `/bin/sh -c` instead of using `execvp(2)` directly.

The same holds true for the `system`, `exec`, `open2`, etc functions in perl, and is documented in `perldoc -f system`.

A simpler example:

```
$ foo(){ echo foo; }; export -f foo

$ perl -e 'system shift' '/bin/bash -c foo\ a'
/bin/bash: foo: command not found
$ perl -e 'system shift' '/bin/bash -c foo'
foo
$ perl -e 'system shift' '/bin/bash -c "foo"'
/bin/bash: foo: command not found

$ perl -e 'open F, "|-", shift' '/bin/bash -c foo\ a'
/bin/bash: foo: command not found
$ perl -e 'open F, "|-", shift' '/bin/bash -c foo'
foo
```

The work-around is to run external commands with the user's `$ENV{SHELL}`, which will let them use any shell features seamlessly:

```
perl -e 'open F, "|-", $ENV{SHELL}, "-c", "@ARGV"' '/bin/bash -c "foo a"'
```

Comment: `$ENV{SHELL}` is not guaranteed to preserve those env vars though. The only shell that is guaranteed to is `bash` as that's a `bash` feature. I'd say the correct way would be to do `perl -e 'system @ARGV' bash -c 'foo a'` here.

Comment: Which is just right, because the user may not care about `bash`'s exported functions, but may expect to use other features of their shell transparently in the commands passed as arguments to that perl program.

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble with portability of an exported bash function across systems.
Yes, that makes sense.

To improve portability simply

```
$ touch myfunc
$ chmod a+x myfunc
```

and put the desired bash code in that file,
starting with a `#! /usr/bin/env bash` shebang line.
(`env` obeys `$PATH`, you see.)

Then you're relying on the ability of programs
(including gnu parallel) to fork+exec,
rather than on how well variants like `sh` or `dash` conform to `bash` behavior.