# Why is my BASH_FUNC_foobar%% environment variable unset in shell subprocesses?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm messing around with the security of a setuid binary (with the intention of disclosing anything I find to the author, obviously). I'm pretty sure it has an arbitrary code execution vulnerability because it invokes a shell script and it doesn't sanitize the environment - I thought of bash's `export -f` but I can't actually make a proof of concept work.

The basic problem is that for some reason, `BASH_FUNC_foobar%%` (where `foobar` is the function being exported) is mysteriously vanishing from the environment in some subprocesses. It works with non-shells:

```
% env 'BASH_FUNC_foobar%%=() { echo pwd lol; }' env | grep BASH
BASH_FUNC_foobar%%=() { echo pwd lol; }
```

But if I replace `env | grep BASH` with the actual program name, modified to dump the environment (basically just `system("env")` in the C source), this variable is removed. The same happens when I specify `sh` as the command to invoke, although weirdly enough, if I specify `bash` then the function is picked up just fine.

Note that on my test system `/bin/sh` is provided by `dash`.

What the heck is going on? Why is this variable disappearing?

Comment: How do you dump the environment in the program? What shell is your `sh`?

Comment: Possibly related: [Bash - Functions in Shell Variables](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/233091)

Comment: Possibly related: [When was the shellshock (CVE-2014-6271/7169) bug introduced, and what is the patch that fully fixes it?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/157495)

Comment: dash filters the inbound environment to only valid variable names, if that's your `sh`.

Comment: @ilkkachu edited the question to include those answers.

Comment: @strugee, yep, the use of `system()` clears that one up. Something like `extern char **environ; for (char **p = environ; *p; p++) printf("%s\n", *p);` should show the ones with non-valid names too.

Comment: @strugee, also note that is Bash detects it's running setuid, it doesn't load exported functions, so the program might not be immediately vulnerable that way even if `sh` is Bash (though it should still clear the environment). See the final point here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On many linux systems, `/bin/sh` is actually `/bin/dash`.

As already mentioned in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498905/why-is-my-bash-func-foobar-environment-variable-unset-in-shell-subprocesses#comment918542_498905) by @MichaelHomer `/bin/dash` will sanitize the environment and remove from it any strings which are not of the form `/^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*=.*/`, and that includes the `BASH_FUNC_foo%%=...`, because of the `%%`.

This is quite specific to `dash` and to OpenBSD's `ksh` (and `mksh` which is based on it) -- other shells won't bother to do that.

Example, on debian where `/bin/sh` is `dash`:

```
$ env - '@#%=' 'foo%%=bar' /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/printenv
PWD=/your/cwd
$ env - '@#%=' 'foo%%=bar' /usr/bin/printenv
@#%=
foo%%=bar
$ env - '@#%=' 'foo%%=bar' /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/printenv
[...]
@#%=
foo%%=bar
```

For a source reference you can look at [src/var.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/var.c?id=284b9192ed12a80b35fa7b9b85d75055887b64e9#n131) in the `dash` source:

```
    initvar();
    for (envp = environ ; *envp ; envp++) {
            p = endofname(*envp);
            if (p != *envp && *p == '=') {
                    setvareq(*envp, VEXPORT|VTEXTFIXED);
            }
    }
```

When `dash` exec's another binary, the `env` argument passed to `execve` is built from the variable list dynamically (with `listvars(VEXPORT, VUNSET, 0)` as called via the `environment()` macro).

Comment: this explains it. libc `system()` will also invoke `/bin/sh` which explains why the C program was mysteriously deleting these variables, too.