# How to export functions from .profile during graphical login

Tags: bash, gdm3

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with GDM. I am trying to export some bash functions from my `.profile`.

As explained in [this very good resource](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles), the main difference between `.bashrc` and `.profile` is that the latter is executed only on login shells.

I am already successfully using `.profile` to export some env variables that would be not appropriate in `.bashrc`. Therefore, I know that `.profile` is being successfully sourced even on graphical login shells. For example, my `$PATH` definition looks something like this:

```bsh
export PATH="something/bin:$PATH"
```

Had I put this in `.bashrc`, `"something/bin"` would get inserted again every time I run a subshell:

```bsh
$ echo $PATH
something/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ bash
$ echo $PATH
something/bin:something/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

However, exporting a function like the following does not seem to work for graphical logins:

```bsh
hello () { echo "hello"; }
export -f hello
```

It works correctly both when doing `bash -l` and from a console login.

So, the question is: why, if apparently `.profile` gets sourced (env vars are successfully exported, and it seems to be explicitly sourced in `/etc/gdm3/Xsession`) then exporting functions does not work?

Comment: What shell sources `.profile` though? There are a few ordinary shells will read the file when invoked as a login shell. Do you know for a fact that GDM starts a `bash` login shell, and not a `sh` login shell?

Comment: No, I do not know for sure. I guess at least some of my assumptions are wrong, otherwise, this should work (unless it is a bug). However, my login shell is `bash` (specified in `/etc/passwd`) and the shebang of `/etc/gdm3/Xsession` is `#!/bin/bash`. I also confirmed that bash is being used to source `.profile` by printing `$BASH_VERSION` to a file.

Comment: Ok, so `bash` reads the file. Good. The next thing to note is that an exported function is likely only usable in a `bash` shell child process. I've just tested exporting a function, starting _another (non-`bash`) shell_, and the function is not there. Nor is it there if I start `bash` from that other shell. It _is_ there if I start a `bash` shell from the first shell. This means that if you start an interactive `bash` shell from something that is not `bash`, the function may not be in the environment.

Comment: I suspect this may be a manifestation of [this question's issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498905/why-is-my-bash-func-foobar-environment-variable-unset-in-shell-subprocesses): an intervening `dash` (or `sh`, on Ubuntu), or `system()`, will strip out the exported functions' environment variables.

Comment: @tyrion if you're running gnome, notice that the `gnome-session` script has a `/bin/sh` shebang, which means that it will be run with `dash`, which will wipe off all funny environment variables, as described in Michael Homer's comment. You may change that shebang by hand to `#! /bin/bash` (not really recommended), but it will be changed back at the next upgrade of the `gnome-session-bin` package.

Comment: @tyrion instead of modifying the /usr/bin/gnome-session or other system file, you can now also bind-mount another file on it. Please mention what X11 session you're using (gnome, mate, custom, etc)

Comment: @mosvy I am using gnome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a specific instance of the issue described in "[Why is my BASH_FUNC_foobar%% environment variable unset in shell subprocesses?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498905)".

When you export a function in `bash`, it creates an environment variable with a special name:

```
$ foo () { echo hello; }
$ export -f foo
$ env

...

BASH_FUNC_foo%%=() {  echo hello
}

...
```

The shell does this because shell functions can't *really* be exported as *functions*, so they are converted to "special environment variables" instead. Environment variables can only ever be simple key-value string pairs.

When a `bash` shell inherits an environment with these sorts of environment variables, it know that they are `bash` functions, and instantiates the functions with the appropriate names.

According to [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap08.html):

> Environment variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2017 consist solely of **uppercase letters, digits, and the `<underscore>` (`_`)** from the characters defined in Portable Character Set and do not begin with a digit. **Other characters may be permitted by an implementation; applications shall tolerate the presence of such names.** Uppercase and lowercase letters shall retain their unique identities and shall not be folded together. The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.

According to this passage, environment variables containing `%` in their names are permitted, but other shells, for example the shells that masquerade as `/bin/sh` on some systems (`dash` on Ubuntu for example, and `ksh` on OpenBSD), sanitises the environment and removes any environment variables whose names contain characters  other than the explicitly allowed ones.

The `/bin/sh` shell is used when an application calls `system()` to start another process.

**This all means** that if your `/bin/sh` is `dash` (which it is on Ubuntu), and if the environment of the final interactive `bash` shell that you get in a terminal was ever passed (via inheritance from parent process to child process) through a call to `system()`, or in some other way was inherited by `/bin/sh` on the way, then your functions would have disappeared<sup>1</sup>.

**The workaround** is to define your functions in `~/.bashrc` or wherever you define your aliases. Or to get your terminal to spawn a `bash` login shell.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Unfortunately, I don't run either of GDM or Ubuntu, so I can't currently run `strace` on the processes involved in the login procedure to see what actually happens there.</sub>

---

Example showing a function disappearing between one `bash` shell and another, when the other `bash` shell is invoked by `dash`:

```
$ foo () { echo hello; }
$ export -f foo

$ dash -c 'bash -c foo'
bash: foo: command not found
```

Example of using `yash` instead, which does not remove the function:

```
$ yash -c 'bash -c foo'
hello
```

Likewise, `ksh` on OpenBSD sanitises, while `ksh93` and `zsh` do not:

```
$ ksh -c 'bash -c foo'
bash: foo: command not found
$ ksh93 -c 'bash -c foo'
hello
$ zsh -c 'bash -c foo'
hello
```

Note that in all cases where the output is `hello` above, the intermediate shell is totally unaware that the specially named environment variable constitutes a function:

```
$ yash -c 'foo'
yash: no such command `foo'
$ ksh93 -c 'foo'
ksh93: foo: not found
$ zsh -c 'foo'
zsh:1: command not found: foo
```

Comment: "applications shall tolerate the presence of such names."
Doesn't this mean that dash should not strip those names and just leave them there?

Comment: @tyrion `/bin/sh` is what the text calls "an implementation", i.e. a utility described by the standard that implements the standard. An "application" is generally a script or program _using_ the utilities and interfaces described by POSIX (i.e. not a standard utility, but it may be a script you write, or GDM or `gnome-terminal`). The word "may" (just before the bit you quoted) allows `/bin/sh` to _not_ permit environment variables with names containing characters outside of the given set of characters.