# Adding function to .profile not available in terminal after logging out and logging back in

Tags: bash, fedora, gnome

So my `.profile` looks like this:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

if [ -f "$HOME/.local/share/profile" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.local/share/profile"
fi


# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export VISUAL=nano
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
stty -ixon

function test-func {
        echo test-func
}

alias test-alias='echo test-alias'
```

When I log into Gnome (on Fedora 35) and open the terminal emulator, I can't execute the function `test-func`.

```
$ test-func
bash: test-func: command not found
```

But when I put the function in my `.bashrc` file and re-logout and log back in, I am able to execute the `test-func` function.

Is there a reason why functions added to `.profile` are not available in the environment?

Edit: So I noticed that when I log in using a non-graphical login (using the Ctrl + Alt + F3 trick), the `test-func` function is available. Is there a reason why Gnome doesn't make functions in the `.profile` available to non-login shells?

Edit 2: I also noticed that using a POSIX-compliant syntax for the functions (`func-name () { ... }` instead of `function func-name { ... }`) had no effect.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work

Comment: What login manager are you using? GDM?

Comment: @frabjous whatever the default one that is included with Fedora 35

Comment: @thanasisp That answer doesn't explain why functions in `.profile` aren't loaded in Gnome. I know the `.profile` is being sourced when I log in, because I can put environment variables in there and they are available in my terminal emulator as well as applications launched directly from Gnome.

Comment: I believe it is because on Fedora and other modern systemd-logind based login managers, the graphical login is mediated through the `systemd --user` daemon. It inherits the environment variables of the login shell that launched it, but it directly executes the processes that start your UI. Your gnome-terminal is a child of that process. As far as the shell in your terminal can tell, it has the inherited environment variables but no functions.

Comment: I wonder if the fact that `function test-func { ... }` isn't [POSIX compatible](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05) is a factor here? Does it behave differently with `test-func () { ... }` ?

Comment: @wheeler I meant [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88108/216907) answer of this post, the links to wikis could be useful for other major distributions, but I see you updated with Fedora. Perhaps you could find something similar into your distribution's documentation.

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` file? Are other things set in your `.profile` working as expected? The variables, for example?

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the question to reflect trying to use a POSIX-compliant syntax, it had no effect.

Comment: @terdon No `~/.bash_profile` exists, and the `.profile` is otherwise working as expected because the environment variables defined in there _are_ available in the terminal emulator after login. Additionally, if I add `touch ~/profile-test-file` to my `~/.profile`, the file gets created when I log in. When I add `touch ~/bashrc-test-file` to my `~/.bashrc` file, the file gets created when I start the terminal emulator.

Comment: What does `ls -l /bin/sh` give? And `grep $(id -un) /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f7`? Also, you can list all the environment variables and functions in bash by calling the builtin `set` without parameters (`set | less` to page it).

Comment: After checking in QEMU, Fedora seems to have /bin/sh set to bash. Though it doesn't explain the issue in that case, as Bash doesn't sanitize variables even when executed as /bin/sh, this answer offers a possible workaround, which is to set the shell in GNOME Terminal as a login shell: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505397/367454 Do note that the default /etc/bashrc and /etc/profile in Fedora in the comments contain a mention of which of those files should specifically hold functions.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more like a comment, but since I don't have enough reputation, here are what I've got:

- This issue is not specifically related to Gnome, I'm on KDE and I'm having it too;
- If I put the function into `~/.bash_profile`, it will be available. Could you confirm the same? If it also happens to you that way, then we have another clue: Fedora treats `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` differently regarding non-login shells.

It actually treats them differently in regard to login shells: if you login with X, `~/.profile` gets sourced first, even before `~/.bash_profile`, but when there's no GUI, only `~/.bash_profile` is sourced (as [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) describes). You can run `journalctl` to see that `/etc/X11/xinit/Xsession` inits the GUI session, and that `Xsession` script sources `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common` which seems to exist only on Fedora and which in turn sources `~/.profile`.

My two cents.